# Defining and Accessing an image attr in an Android custom view

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-custom-view, attr, togglebutton

I'm new'ish to Android.  Not super new but new enough.

I want to extend a ToggleButton so I can compose what it will look like.

In order to do this I've defined three attributes in attrs.xml.  This is my first problem.  I want to be able to specify an image resource in my control through markup.  I'm trying to create a custom attribute for this but I feel like I'm failing.  See togbtn_image below.

The custom attributes:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="BBI_Droid">
        <attr name="togbtn_image" format="reference" />
        <attr name="togbtn_bold_description" format="string"/>
        <attr name="togbtn_minor_description" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The goal is for the togbtn_image to be specified as something like:

togbtn_image = "@drawable/an_icon"

Something like this in my custom ToggleButton?  (where iv is an ImageView)

```
        iv.setImageResource(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.BBI_Droid_togbtn_image, -1));
```

I then need to load it within the custom view's class but I'm not quite sure how to access it.

I know what I want to do, but I'm missing the link to put it all together.  Hopefully someone can help me.

```
public class togbtn_with_description extends ToggleButton {
    private View mValue;
    private ImageView mImage;

    public togbtn_with_description(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.BBI_Droid, 0, 0);
        String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.BBI_Droid_togbtn_bold_description);
        String minorText = a.getString(R.styleable.BBI_Droid_togbtn_minor_description);


        // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ACCESS THAT togbtn_image resource AND ASSIGN IT TO AN IMAGEVIEW
        // THAT IS TO BE CREATED AS PART OF THIS TOGGLE BUTTON.  ONCE I GET THAT RESOURCE,
        // I'LL THEN SETUP THE LAYOUT FOR THIS TOGGLEBUTTON

        a.recycle();

        // more stuff
    }
}
```

Am I way off base here?  I have a strong WPF background by the way so I feel that may be painting my point of view a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...

Ultimately what I ended up doing was creating a custom layout and inflating it into a RelativeLayout custom view instead of a togglebutton.

```
iv.setImageResource(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.BBI_Droid_togbtn_image, -1));
```

To set the value.